# Saving each iteration in a for loop as a data frame

Tags: r

First off, yes I have researched this and yes I have seen several answers that should solve my problem BUT I cannot seem to apply them to my situation so I am going straight to my source and hoping someone can get the concept through my thick skull with my data.  This is an obviously much smaller example. I am trying to filter our rows which contain a value from a vector in any of the Code_ columns and have them save as a data frame for each iteration.  Right now, this code ads a mutated column on each pass to show which value from the code vector was used for that filter.  This of course results in much duplication and I have to still pull the output apart to get each iteration into its own separate df.

```
transaction <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
Code_1 <- c("QD","QK","QI","QE","QH")
Code_2 <- c("QE","QB","SA","QG","QC")
Code_3 <- c("QG","QH","DI","QK","QI")
Code_4 <- c("QK","QC","QD","QB","SA")

df <- data.frame(transaction, Code_1, Code_2, Code_3, Code_4)

codes <- c("QD","QH","SA")

test <- data.frame(NULL)

for(i in codes){
  tmp <- df %>% filter(Code_1 == i | Code_2 == i | Code_3 == i| Code_4 == i) %>% mutate(interation = 
i)
  test <- rbind(test, tmp)

}
```

I get an output that captures all the rows I want to but I still have to manipulate them into separate dfs based on the mutated column "iteration"  Is there some way to lose the mutated column and save each iteration as a df as it loops. I have tried several examples and tried to play with a couple of apply scenarios but this is the only thing I have been able to get to work.

Sorry for confusion with output

In a perfect world I want each iteration to output a unique tibble/df. I want an output as if I had just run something like this but a thousand time over hundreds of codes. I don't want a list.  I want unique individual outputs.

```
QD <- df %>% filter(Code_1 == "QD" | Code_2 == "QD" | Code_3 == "QD"| 
Code_4 == "QD")
QH <- df %>% filter(Code_1 == "QH" | Code_2 == "QH" | Code_3 == "QH"| 
Code_4 == "QH")
SA <- df %>% filter(Code_1 == "SA" | Code_2 == "SA" | Code_3 == "SA"| 
Code_4 == "SA")
```

Comment: You don't want column `iteration` in the final result?

Comment: I don't know if my answer is a good start ... your last paragraph is a little confusing. It would help if you provided expected output given your sample data here. Thanks!

Comment: To get the matching codes found in each line you could do something like: `df$foundCode <- sapply(apply(df[-1], 1, function(x) codes[codes %in% x]), paste, collapse = ", ")`, and use the output to filter, etc..

Comment: If you look at my solution you will see that while `test` is a list it is actually a list of the tibbles you requested.  Most of the others are as well you just need to skip the `rbind` step

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `tidyverse` solution.  We'll name the input vector to make clear the output `test` is actually a named list of tibbles as desired

```
codes <- c("QD","QH","SA")
names(codes) <- codes

library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

test <- purrr::map(codes, function(i){
  df %>% 
    rowwise() %>%
    filter(i %in% c_across(Code_1:Code_4)) %>% 
    mutate(interation = i) %>%
    ungroup
  
})

# test has everything but they are all named so ...

test$QD
#> # A tibble: 2 x 6
#>   transaction Code_1 Code_2 Code_3 Code_4 interation
#>         <dbl> <chr>  <chr>  <chr>  <chr>  <chr>     
#> 1           1 QD     QE     QG     QK     QD        
#> 2           3 QI     SA     DI     QD     QD
```

Comment: It seems there is no way to get individual outputs outside a list.  this is probably the closest I can get or just pop it out as one df and filter what I need.  Helpful to see the counts here though.  Problem I ran into though was my R not recognizing the c-across function even after updating package.  Mcuh appreciate all the input though.

Comment: Did you try all the usual things after you update `dplyr` like restarting your rsession so if could find `c_across`?  What version of `dplyr` are you running?  If you can't get it to work `filter(Code_1 == i | Code_2 == i | Code_3 == i| Code_4 == i)` will also work

Comment: If you really want every tibble available in your global environment separately then `list2env(test, .GlobalEnv)` will do that for you.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a `lapply` solution, with no need for a `tmp` data.frame.

```
codes <- c("QD","QH","SA")

test <- lapply(codes, function(i){
  df %>% 
    filter(Code_1 == i | Code_2 == i | Code_3 == i| Code_4 == i) %>% 
    mutate(interation = i)
})
test

test <- do.call(rbind, test)
test
#  transaction Code_1 Code_2 Code_3 Code_4 interation
#1           1     QD     QE     QG     QK         QD
#2           3     QI     SA     DI     QD         QD
#3           2     QK     QB     QH     QC         QH
#4           5     QH     QC     QI     SA         QH
#5           3     QI     SA     DI     QD         SA
#6           5     QH     QC     QI     SA         SA
```

Answer (score 3):

Growing frames row-by-row is logically sound but scales *horribly*: with each row added, the entire frame is copied in memory. This means that when you have 100 rows, to add 1 row, you have the first 100 rows in memory *twice*.

The way around it is to typically save the rows in a `list`, and then combine them manually *in one step*.

```r
out <- list()
for(i in codes){
  tmp <- df %>% filter(Code_1 == i | Code_2 == i | Code_3 == i| Code_4 == i) %>% mutate(interation = i)
  out <- c(out, list(tmp))
}

out
# [[1]]
#   transaction Code_1 Code_2 Code_3 Code_4 interation
# 1           1     QD     QE     QG     QK         QD
# 2           3     QI     SA     DI     QD         QD
# [[2]]
#   transaction Code_1 Code_2 Code_3 Code_4 interation
# 1           2     QK     QB     QH     QC         QH
# 2           5     QH     QC     QI     SA         QH
# [[3]]
#   transaction Code_1 Code_2 Code_3 Code_4 interation
# 1           3     QI     SA     DI     QD         SA
# 2           5     QH     QC     QI     SA         SA
do.call(rbind, out)
#   transaction Code_1 Code_2 Code_3 Code_4 interation
# 1           1     QD     QE     QG     QK         QD
# 2           3     QI     SA     DI     QD         QD
# 3           2     QK     QB     QH     QC         QH
# 4           5     QH     QC     QI     SA         QH
# 5           3     QI     SA     DI     QD         SA
# 6           5     QH     QC     QI     SA         SA
```

I should add that I retained the `for` loop to be similar to your starting code; Rui's suggestion to use `lapply` is a step in the "better" direction.

Answer (score 1):

We could create a logical expression with `rowSums`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
map(codes, ~ 
       df %>% 
         filter(rowSums(select(., 
                starts_with('Code')) == .x) > 0) %>%
             mutate(interaction = .x)
       )
#[[1]]
#  transaction Code_1 Code_2 Code_3 Code_4 interaction
#1           1     QD     QE     QG     QK          QD
#2           3     QI     SA     DI     QD          QD

#[[2]]
#  transaction Code_1 Code_2 Code_3 Code_4 interaction
#1           2     QK     QB     QH     QC          QH
#2           5     QH     QC     QI     SA          QH

#[[3]]
#  transaction Code_1 Code_2 Code_3 Code_4 interaction
#1           3     QI     SA     DI     QD          SA
#2           5     QH     QC     QI     SA          SA
```