# Efficiently concatenate tibble of outputs from for-loop

Tags: r, loops, tidyverse

I have some complex analysis code in a `for` loop and am trying to compile the outputs in a single dataframe / tibble. Following the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63235239/saving-each-iteration-in-a-for-loop-as-a-data-frame) I am avoiding modifying the main output tibble within the loop, instead trying to append the output of each iteration to a list (or similar) and concatenating it after. But I'm having trouble with the exact syntax and getting the dimensions right.

Specifically, I have something like this:

```
months <- c("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr")

iter_out <- list() # Container for output

## Iterate over each month of data
for (i in 1:length(months)) {

  ## Subset data
  iter_data <- data %>% filter(month < months[[i]])
  ## Note that actual operation is more complex than this, so simply grouping by month and doing a grouped apply won't work

  ## Run analysis  
  output_1 <- run_first_analysis(iter_data)
  output_2 <- run_second_analysis(iter_data)

  iter_out <- c(iter_out, list(months[[i]], output_1, output_2))
}
```

(Note that to further complicate matters, `output_1` and `output_2` are themselves lists as well, and I'd like to keep them that way.)

From the loop (or from `iter_out`), I'd like to get an output like this:

```
# A tibble: 4 × 3
  month  output_1   output_2 
  <chr>   <list>     <list>
1 "Jan" <list [3]> <list [3]>
2 "Feb" <list [3]> <list [3]>
3 "Mar" <list [3]> <list [3]>
4 "Apr" <list [3]> <list [3]>
```

With the outputs in list-columns, and the first column / rownames being the month. However, all I've managed to get is everything in a single 12 x 1 tibble instead.

What's the best way to concatenate the iterative outputs the way I'd like?

Comment: try `for (i in months)` instead of the current `for (i in 1:length(months))`. The index vector to loop over can be a character vector too, I does not HAVE to be a sequence

Comment: @GuedesBF I'm not sure how that will help with the main problem I'm having (getting the right shape of output / combined output), unless there's something underlying the parsing that I don't understand (which is entirely possible! XD)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer you linked to warned about growing your output with every iteration of a for loop. The solution to this isn't to avoid using data frames altogether, but to initialise a container for them. Your solution involves growing a list rather than a data frame, so will still be inefficient for large numbers of iterations.

To make your code more efficient, you need to initialise an empty list of the correct length, and then fill this list with values in the for loop:

```r
months <- c("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr")

# Create an empty list of length 5
iter_out <- vector("list", length(months))

## Iterate over each month of data
for (i in 1:length(months)) {
  
  ## Subset data
  iter_data <- data %>% filter(month < months[[i]])
  ## Note that actual operation is more complex than this, so simply grouping by month and doing a grouped apply won't work
  
  ## Run analysis  
  output_1 <- run_first_analysis(iter_data)
  output_2 <- run_second_analysis(iter_data)
  
  # Set the relevant item in the list to your data
  iter_out[[i]] <- tibble(
    month = months[[i]], 
    output_1 = list(output_1), 
    output_2 = list(output_2)
  )
}
```

Combining the resulting list can be easily done with `dplyr::bind_rows()` or `purrr::list_rbind()` (I've created a super basic example list to demonstrate this).

```r
library(tidyverse)

iter_out <- list(
  tibble(month = "x", output_1 = list(list()), output_2 = list(list())),
  tibble(month = "x", output_1 = list(list()), output_2 = list(list()))
)

iter_out
#> [[1]]
#> # A tibble: 1 × 3
#>   month output_1   output_2  
#>   <chr> <list>     <list>    
#> 1 x     <list [0]> <list [0]>
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> # A tibble: 1 × 3
#>   month output_1   output_2  
#>   <chr> <list>     <list>    
#> 1 x     <list [0]> <list [0]>

list_rbind(iter_out)
#> # A tibble: 2 × 3
#>   month output_1   output_2  
#>   <chr> <list>     <list>    
#> 1 x     <list [0]> <list [0]>
#> 2 x     <list [0]> <list [0]>

bind_rows(iter_out)
#> # A tibble: 2 × 3
#>   month output_1   output_2  
#>   <chr> <list>     <list>    
#> 1 x     <list [0]> <list [0]>
#> 2 x     <list [0]> <list [0]>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create nested data, you can use `tibble`.  It's like this.

```
library(dplyr)
months <- c("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr")

iter_out <- tibble(month = character(), output_1 = list(), output_2 = list()) # Container for output

## Iterate over each month of data
for (i in 1:length(months)) {
  
  ## Subset data
  iter_data <- data %>% filter(month < months[[i]])
  ## Note that actual operation is more complex than this, so simply grouping by month and doing a grouped apply won't work
  
  ## Run analysis  
  output_1 <- run_first_analysis(iter_data)
  output_2 <- run_second_analysis(iter_data)
  
  iter_out <- bind_rows(iter_out, tibble(month = months[[i]], output_1 = list(output_1), output_2 = list(output_2)))
}
```

But I prefer to use `lapply` instead of `for` loop.

```
library(dplyr)
months <- c("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr")

lapply(months, function(x){
  ## Subset data
  iter_data <- data %>% filter(month < x)
  ## Note that actual operation is more complex than this, so simply grouping by month and doing a grouped apply won't work
  
  ## Run analysis  
  output_1 <- run_first_analysis(iter_data)
  output_2 <- run_second_analysis(iter_data)
  
  tibble(month = x, output_1 = list(output_1), output_2 = list(output_2))
}) %>% 
  bind_rows()
```